# How to get some values from a 3d array into a new array inside a while loop

Tags: php

I would like to get a CSV export working where the user picks some optional fields to export with the required fields. I'm having trouble just adding the list of fields to export into this csv export method.

The list of fields i want to be part of the export ends up in the $fields array, but I'm not sure how to integrate that into the export loop for each row.

```php
// database conection stuff and $_POST data validation/sanitation above here, not relevant. From a CSV export form.
$exportToCSVQuery = " SELECT $allRequestedFields' FROM my_table ";

// if the (run query) is valid then...                                                                                                                                                              
    if ($exportToCSVResult = mysqli_query($mysqli, $exportToCSVQuery))  {
    // count number of rows in result.
    $exportToCSVResultNumRows = mysqli_num_rows($exportToCSVResult);
// if there is at least one result.
if ($exportToCSVResultNumRows > 0 ) {
    if ($safeDelimiter == 'Comma')  {
        $delimiter = ",";
    }

   elseif ($safeDelimiter == 'Semi-colon')  {
    $delimiter = ";";
    }
    else{
       $delimiter = ",";
        }
//create a file pointer
$f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
//set column headers
$fields = array('ID', 'Name', 'em', 'type', 'reason', 'result', 'status', 'notes', 'datetime', 'requestedby', 'requestedbycitrixid', 'week', 'period', 'year', 'historylog');

// put required and optional fields together from the form.
$fields = $fields+$safeFieldsArray;
fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter);
//create $linedata information, formatted in a php assoc row format.
//flip the $fields array so the values become the keys, needed for the next step.
$fieldsFlipped = array_flip($fields);
//output each row of the data, format line as csv and write to file pointer
while($exporttocsvrow = $exporttocsvresult->fetch_assoc()){
$fieldsarrayforlinedata = array_intersect_key($exporttocsvrow,$fieldsFlipped);
// flip array
$flippedfieldsarrayforlinedata = array_flip($fieldsarrayforlinedata);
fputcsv($f, $flippedfieldsarrayforlinedata, $delimiter);
}
//move back to beginning of file
fseek($f, 0);
//set headers to download file rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $safeFilename . '";');
//output all remaining data on a file pointer
fpassthru($f);
}
else    {
Echo 'No Data to Export';
}
}
else    {
$exportToCSVResultErr = "Error: " .mysqli_error($mysqli) ;
trigger_error("Query Error: ".$exportToCSVQuery." Error:" $exportToCSVResultErr, E_USER_WARNING);
        }
```

Edit: I tried adding something based on Pradeep’s answer below to the loop like so:

```php
while($exporttocsvrow = $exporttocsvresult->fetch_assoc()){



$fieldsarrayforlinedata = array_intersect_key($exportToCSVRow,$fieldsFlipped);

unset($valuesArray);
$valuesArray = array();
foreach ($fieldsFlipped as $key){
foreach ($exportToCSVRow[$key] as $values)  {
        $valuesArray[] = $values;
                                                                            }
                                                    }

fputcsv($f, $valuesArray, $delimiter);
}
```

But this just results in the CSV with headings and blank data. I guess I'm probably adding that loop incorrectly.

Comment: `array_intersect_key` works based on the _keys_ in both arrays - but your `$keys` array has a _zero-based, numeric_ index. What you currently have in there as the _values_, needs to _become_ the keys. `$keys = array_flip($keys);`, and _then_ use `array_intersect_key` …

Comment: @04FS I apoligise, because I was posting this as a generic version of my actual code, I missed posting that part. I actually already had flipped that array and I have another array that I should have used in this explanation. I will update the question.

Comment: Please show the actual code, in order - and not just several lines on their own, without proper context. (Although Pradeep’s answer should be able to solve the task already, it is just using an explicit loop, instead of doing this via array functions.)

Comment: @04FS Ok, I'm updating it now. I have previously found starting to post a question where I have explained and re-written it has led me to the answer without having to actually complete posting, so that is why I did it that way I guess.

Comment: Combining both, array_intersect_key and the foreach loop, makes rather little sense - they’re supposed to do the same thing. I don’t know why you are doing `array_flip($fieldsarrayforlinedata)` - that should have the field names as keys, put you want to write the values to your CSV, so why flip it?

Comment: @04FS I'm just randomly guessing now because I've leaving the realms of what I can follow in my head. I usually debug stuff by dumping vars, but because this page is not verbose, there is nowhere for me to do that as it goes, so I find it hard to follow what is going wrong/right at each step. I'm sorry, I'm not trying to be difficult on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help to get the desired output.

```
   $row=array('fieldA'=>array('data1','data2','data2','data3'),'fieldB'=>array('data1','data2','data3'),'fieldC'=>array('data1','data2','data3'));

   $key=array('fieldA','fieldB');

   foreach($key as $key){
        foreach($row[$key] as $values){
        echo $values; 
        }

    }
```